# Why doesn't Xcode have an ios framework option?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, unity-game-engine, build-automation

I've seen project such as `ios-universal-framework`, but I want to know why `XCode` `iOS` does not natively support having a framework. Is it some kind of legal issue. The static library option is not good enough because I want to be able to use `.dylib` files in my framework.

A little background on what I want to do with a framework. I have a project that is generated from `Unity3D`, and when we update, we have to manually add back all of our project changes.

What I want is to use a framework that can store most of those external libraries and resources to make it easier to upgrade our project when updates are released.

Comment: It would be wonderful if Xcode had an option for a project that can work as a library and resource framework. This would make it much easier to maintain our projects. I found something that helps, but it didn't quite do the trick. http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a security perspective no code is allowed to be dynamically loaded, thus only static libraries are allowed.

It is possible to create static psudo-frameworks. Take a look at GitHub [iOS-Universal-Framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework).

Comment: I guess the .dylib files don't matter much. I don't know what their use is on our project anyways. I would like to be able to group our .a files into an easy to use static framework like you've mentioned.

Comment: in the question I mention that I've heard of and looked at that framework. I suppose I should jump into it more and read everything about it.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a PosprocessBuilder as described in the [build pipeline](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html) described in the Unity3d Documentation.

You can manage the Xcode configurations in this pipeline using scripts like the [Xcode Zerg](https://github.com/ddribin/zerg_xcode).

I've used one python script written by a guy called [Calvin Rien](https://github.com/darktable) that worked really well, if you want to know more about [this script this blog post should give you a hint](http://www.keepcalmandrevert.com/blog/2012/11/xcode-project-editor/).

What you really need to look for to you automate the these steps is to look for posts of Continuous Integration using Unity 3d and iOS like this one:

[Unity3d: from commit to deployment onto tester devices in 20 min using Jenkins](http://lacostej.blogspot.com.br/2012/03/unity3d-from-commit-to-deployment-onto.html)

Comment: This is a very interesting proposition. I would be able to have these post build processes add subprojects, frameworks, build dependencies, etc?

Comment: yes, if you use the Unity3d Forums you may have found threads talking about of the Prime31 Plugins. All the links I've posted are the steps to achieve the same effect as the Plugins created by him.